# Why doesn't my <div> move when I press w a s d?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I just want to make it move, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```js
//code.js

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const blockElement = document.querySelector('.block');
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;

  function updatePosition() {
    blockElement.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
  }

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'w':
        y -= 10;
        break;
      case 'a':
        x -= 10;
        break;
      case 's':
        y += 10;
        break;
      case 'd':
        x += 10;
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }

    updatePosition();
  });
});
```

```css
/* CSS styles */
*{
  margin:0;padding:0;
} 

body{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block{
  background:#444444;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:2px solid black;
  height:50px;
  width:50px
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>g</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="block" id="block></div>
<script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Языком по умолчанию в этом форуме является английский; для перевода можно воспользоваться переводчиком. 

Relevant infos need to be included in your question as text, not as pictures of text. Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you. Please provide a runnable minimal reproducible example which demonstrates the problem. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the tour and read How to Ask and its linked resources. Also inserted code can and should be formated and not contain (that many) typos.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the div's position to absolute or fixed to move it around.

Minimal working example:

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  console.log(e.key);
  const key = e.key;

  switch (key) {
    case "ArrowUp":
      myDiv.style.top = myDiv.offsetTop - 10 + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      myDiv.style.top = myDiv.offsetTop + 10 + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowLeft":
      myDiv.style.left = myDiv.offsetLeft - 10 + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      myDiv.style.left = myDiv.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```